# Failing to install wine in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: wine, 22.04, winetricks

I'm new to linux and I'm trying to install wine so I can play Hearthstone.
I following this tutorial: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-battle-net-on-ubuntu-22-04-linux-desktop

I run `winetricks` and everything is OK until Step 3. Then, I get some errors that even if I press OK, they keep reappering and nothing else happens - until I stop the terminal.

Below you can see both images that show up (somewhere between Step 3 and 4)

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqDlv.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqMFw.png)

And here a paste of the terminal while the errors are happening:

```
guin0x@guin0x-server:~$ winetricks
Executing mkdir -p /home/guin0x
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Using winetricks 20210206 - sha256sum: 0f21da98811e0bfda16a7d6d6b8e860a9cedbd4e836c7dd9b02f068d3092ee2e with wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1) and WINEARCH=win64
winetricks GUI enabled, using zenity 3.42.1
Executing w_do_call corefonts
Executing mkdir -p /home/guin0x
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing load_corefonts 
Executing w_do_call andale
Executing mkdir -p /home/guin0x
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing load_andale 
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/guin0x/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp /home/guin0x/.cache/winetricks/corefonts/andale32.exe
------------------------------------------------------
warning: Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine processes in prefix=/home/guin0x/.wine terminate
------------------------------------------------------
Executing wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_register-font.reg
Executing wine64 regedit C:\windows\Temp\_register-font.reg
0100:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0100:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
00f8:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
Executing cp /home/guin0x/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_register-font.reg /tmp/winetricks.WeeZhyWc/_reg_90ad6a9f_10400.reg
Executing wine regedit C:\windows\Temp\_register-font.reg
Executing wine64 regedit C:\windows\Temp\_register-font.reg
0120:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0120:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
0118:fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
Executing cp /home/guin0x/.wine/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp/_register-font.reg /tmp/winetricks.WeeZhyWc/_reg_f6204652_10400.reg
Executing w_do_call arial
Executing mkdir -p /home/guin0x
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

hi again can you try this command in terminal

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
```

have you tried this

```
sudo apt-get install wine64
```

You can also install Hearthstone in lutris, lutris is also like wine.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris.
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

i think that your best bet is to try with linux i am sorry but i thinh is your best bet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Also doesn't work, now this time when I write ```winetricks```, after installing wine32, winbind, I get this output (and winetricks doesn't open):
```guin0x@guin0x-server:~$ winetricks
Executing mkdir -p /home/guin0x
------------------------------------------------------
warning: You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. Note that many verbs only install 32-bit versions of packages. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.```

Comment: the rest of the output: ```------------------------------------------------------
warning: wine cmd.exe /c echo '%AppData%' returned empty string, error message "wine: '/home/guin0x/.wine' is a 64-bit installation, it cannot be used with a 32-bit wineserver." 
------------------------------------------------------```

Comment: Hi, nothing works.. Now I did ```sudo apt remove wine*``` and I think I removed everything related to wine from my ubuntu... If I write the code ```WINEPREFIX="$HOME/prefix32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot``` I get 'no such file or directory'. I could try lutris but I don't like giving up on understanding why something doesn't work... and wine should work easily, right? (I tried with wine32 and when I run ```winetricks``` the same problem happens....)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new, and I'm sitting here struggling to get Darklords to run full-screen ... and maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but my suggestion is that you should install Wine first, and then PlayOnLinux, and then install/run your game from the last one.

Comment: what do you mean by 'PlayOnLinux'?

Comment: I'ts a application you can find under Ubuntu Software, that is a front-end to wine ... the software that runs the old programs like Heartstone or Darklords. Its easy to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out :)

Comment: Please remember to upvote the answer if it works... I need to earn some reputation points, lol

Answer (score 0):

I had lots of problems, then found this combination that worked:

1. sudo apt install wine
2. sudo winecfg
3. sudo cp -R ~root/.wine ~myownusername
4. cd ~
5. sudo chown -R myownusername:myownusername .wine
6. wine The_Program_I_wanted_to_Run